# How to know the trained model is correct?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I use PyTorch Lightning for model training, during which I use [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.html#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint) to save loading points. Finally, I would like to know whether the model is loaded correctly. Let me know if you require further information?

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        filename='tb1000_{epoch: 02d}-{step}',
        monitor='val/acc@1',
        save_top_k=5,
        mode='max')

wandb_logger = pl.loggers.wandb.WandbLogger(
        name=run_name,
        project=args.project,
        entity=args.entity,
        offline=args.offline,
        log_model='all')

model = BYOL(**args.__dict__, num_classes=dm.num_classes)

trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(args, 
         logger=wandb_logger, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

trainer.fit(model, dm)

# Loading and testing
model_test = BYOL(**args.__dict__, num_classes=dm.num_classes)
path = "/tb100_epoch= 819-step=39359.ckpt"
model_test.load_from_checkpoint(path)
```

Comment: Does the load function throw any errors? If no then it is loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The load function  doesn't throw any errors. But when I use model_test to perform k-means, the effect is very poor. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load_from_checkpoint()` will return a model with trained weights, so you need to assign it to a new variable.

```
model_test = model_test.load_from_checkpoint(path)
```

or

```
model_test = BYOL.load_from_checkpoint(path)
```